# jQuery Masonry: Use imagesLoaded when masonry is initialized in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used masonry in my website but it is initialized by HTML. No JS is used. The code:

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
```

I have images in masonry blocks. That is why grid does not set itself as required. Any method to call imagesLoaded function in HTML not in JS? I don't know the simplest way I can explain that to you guys. No example provided in Desandro's website.

Comment: @Bojangles what else I can do ? Nobody answered the question and I think I have to write JS :(

Comment: Yes, you will have to write some JavaScript, although that's not such a bad thing - it keeps your logic separate from the HTML and will be much easier to maintain in the future